# calling StateHasChanged() async in Blazor Server-Side application effects all open browsers, how can I stop this?

Tags: c#, html, async-await, blazor, blazor-server-side

This is my first question here so please go easy on me. :)
I'm also new to Blazor but not c#.

I am building a Blazor server-side application where a user can enter some information and check if it's valid or not based on some data on the server.

So far I have no issues with calling the function of the class that does the lookup and returns a record to display on the browser.
My problem comes when I want to display that information.

In the c# code, I have a variable called `SdItem` which contains the record that comes back from the query.

To display the data on the razor page I use the following lines.

```
@if (SdItem != null)
{
    <div>
        Code: @SdItem.Code<br />
        Desc.: @SdItem.Desc<br />
    </div>
}
```

When `SdItem` gets the data it obviously does not display the information until I call `StateHasChanged();`
This of course throws an exception so I had to change it to `await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);`

Although after this change the information shows on the screen and all seems to be fine, I came across a new issue which I could not find a solution or an explanation anywhere on the internet.

During debugging, MS Edge automatically starts and displays the website.
To test this strange issue I also start Firefox to point to the same local address.
Then I use my smartphone as well and that is where I start the query.
When I get the results back, not only do they show up on the phone but on all active browsers that are currently displaying the site.

Why does this happen and how can I stop it.

At the moment I managed to stop this from happening with an ugly code

```
try { StateHasChanged(); } catch { }
```

This suppresses the exception and the result is only being displayed on the browser that does the request. This is ugly and I don't like to use it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Just as information, in case this could be the reason. The queried data is in a List in a class which is added as a scoped service. But T is a private variable in the code on the razor file.

Comment: That try-catch is misleading about the cause. You have something that is static or Singleton that shouldn't be. Way too little code here, see if you can make a [mre]

Comment: My apologies if the code was not enough. I will try to provide more information, once I did some more troubleshooting. At the moment I narrowed it down to a library I'm using for scanning bar codes using the camera [link](https://github.com/sabitertan/BlazorBarcodeScanner). When I use a simple input box and button there is no issues.

Answer (score 0):

"*When `SdItem` gets the data it obviously does not display the information until I call `StateHasChanged`*" Why is this obvious? I would expect Blazor to update the display whenever displayed data is changed. You should very rarely need to call `StateHasChanged`. This makes me wonder what else is going on.

First thought that springs to mind is that `SdItem` should be a property...

```cs
public Whatever SdItem { get; set; }
```

...and **not** a private field...

```
private Whatever SdItem;
```

I'm not sure if needs to be public, but when using properties, Blazor (almost) always updates the display. When using private fields, if often doesn't.

"*This of course throws an exception*" Again, I don't see why this is so obvious that you say "*of course.*" It all depends on where  you are calling `StateHasChanged`. Yes, if you're inside an `async` block then you'll need to call `InvokeAsync`, but if you arent, then you shouldn't need to do that.

More code would be useful, as its hard to  know exactly what you're doing from the small snippet you provided, but try using a property (if you aren't already), and see if that avoids the need to call `StateHasChanged`.

If not, please update your question with more information.

Comment: Blazor does not care about properties or fields.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Odd, because I have definitely seen a difference. Coming from a background of MVVM in WPF (where this definitely does make a difference) I assumed it  worked the same way. Thanks for the info

Comment: @HenkHolterman Yes it was with Blazor, and no it wasn't a `[Parameter]`, it was with a local variable. I've not spent too much time figuring it out, but have seen many cases where my UI wasn't updated when I used a regular private field, but changing it to an auto-property did cause the UI to update. Maybe I'm completely wrong, but that's just what it seems based on this happening quite a few times. I don't claim to be an expert on Blazor, so could have missed something completely here.